# How to display custom datetime format in highchart?

Tags: c#, datetime, highcharts

I produce a full  DateTime  in c# like as '2016-02-03 11:00:00' and pass it to HighChart that is in js file. i get it like as '2016-02-03T11:00:00'.
Now I display it in xAxis but when I pas to addpoint method it display 00:00:01 .I trying to display it  by change datetime formatting  but not worked for me.

```
                       dateTimeLabelFormats: { //force all formats to be hour:minute:second
                               second: '%H:%M:%S',
                               minute: '%H:%M:%S',
                               hour: '%H:%M:%S',
                               day: '%H:%M:%S',
                               week: '%H:%M:%S',
                               month: '%H:%M:%S',
                               year: '%H:%M:%S'
                           },
```

Comment: Show what have you tried and explain what is not working exactly. [MCVE] would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Any date must be provided as a number - a JavaScript timestamp format (milliseconds since 1970.01.01). For Highcharts data - date must be set as x property of a data point. See possible data formats explained in [this section of Highcharts documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series#1).

You date cannot be a string if you want it by treated as a date in [a datetime type axis](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes) by Highcharts - you need to parse it like in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/type-datetime-irregular/):

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2), 71.5],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3), 106.4],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6), 129.2],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 7), 144.0],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 8), 176.0]
        ]
    }]

});
```